# Merge first column of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes - However, one of the column containts data that can't be merged with the other.

I'm trying to merge this

[image]

with this

[image]

I've tried cbind and merge - The problem with merge is, that the first column in the second picture/dataframe is not a real column.

Comment: Use `rownames_to_column()` from the `tibble` package to set the rownames as a column. Then use `left_join()` from the `dplyr` package to join the two dataframes by country.